# Why does Spongy Castle ignore the bcpg and openpgp packages

Tags: java, android, bouncycastle, openpgp, spongycastle

Does anyone know why [SpongyCastle](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle) is explicitly excluding openpgp and bcpg packages (amongst others) from being built?  I would like to get OpenPGP support working and I will require a number of those classes to do so.

You can find the exclusions in the [pom.xml](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/blob/spongy-master/pom.xml) file.

Out of curiosity, I cloned the repository and tried to include those packages.  It seems to have been as simple as moving the contents of the bzip2 directory into the src directory and removing the 2 exclusions from the POM file.  The result seems to build, and the resulting JAR file contains the classes I needed.  Are there runtime issues that might pop up unpredictably?

Comment: Tracing the origin of those lines back in the history reveals [this commit](https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/commit/2bf8b995ef60203cd9e18c42ff02608780a939e1). Apperently this was a change that made more tests pass, so it *seems* as if the reason is simply "no one tried/ported that code yet".

Comment: Thanks!  A lot of tests fail even without those packages :)

Answer (score 0):

Since v1.47 Spongy Castle has included the [scpg-jdk15on](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22com.madgag%22%20AND%20a%3a%22scpg-jdk15on%22) artifact, supplying all the OpenPGP support from `bcpg-jdk15on`:

https://github.com/rtyley/spongycastle/pull/2#issuecomment-5057038